# if/elseif/else only returning first condition

Tags: php, if-statement, pdo, modx

I am having 2 issues with the following if/elseif/else statement:

```
$rows = array();
$stmt = $dbconnection->query("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE data_field LIKE 'data_selection'");
if ($stmt) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($rows, $row);

        if ($row['something '] == 'selection1') {
            $highlightsarray = array("gridHighlights" => 'text option 1 to display on site');
            $highlights = $row + $highlightsarray;
                } elseif ($row['something'] == 'selection2') {
            $highlightsarray = array("gridHighlights" => 'text option 2 to display on site');
            $highlights = $row + $highlightsarray;
                } else {
            $highlights = "<p>default messaging</p>";
        }
        $fields = $highlights; // this is a placeholder for other if statements I need to add
        $output .= $modx->getChunk('chunk_name', $fields);

    }
}
return $output;
}
```

The first issue I am having is that `==` is not returning any results, if I change that to `=` then it somewhat works.

If I make my statement `($row['something '] = 'selection1')` (with just `=`), then it is only returning the first `if` condition, even if it is not true and should be returning either the `elseif` or `else` condition.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, any assistance is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator, unless value that you are assigning to can't be evaluated to `false`, it will always return `true`, so the following `if` branch will be executed every time.`==` is an equality operator and you _of course_ meant to use it instead – the only explanation you have an issue with it is that variable just doesn't match the string, you should debug your db output to see it yourself.

Comment: Thank you, as soon as I added a `var_dump($row)` then it started behaving correctly. Not sure what the issue was, my strings looked correct. The only problem now is that my else for when nothing matches has strange behavior, but it looks like the rest is ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing this question, doing a var_dump as suggested and reviewing my strings got this working. Here is the final code used:

```
$rows = array();
$stmt = $dbconnection->query("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE data_field LIKE 'data_selection'");
if ($stmt) {
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($rows, $row);

var_dump($row); // to review output

    if ($row['something '] == NULL) {
        $highlights = $row;
            } elseif ($row['something'] == 'selection2') {
        $highlightsarray = array("gridHighlights" => 'text option 2 to display on site');
        $highlights = $row + $highlightsarray;
            } elseif ($row['something'] == 'selection1') {
        $highlightsarray = array("gridHighlights" => 'text option 1 to display on site');
        $highlights = $row + $highlightsarray;
    }
    $fields = $highlights; // this is a placeholder for other if statements I need to add (like $fields = $highlights + $anotherIfStatement;)
    $output .= $modx->getChunk('chunk_name', $fields);

}
}
return $output;
}
```